# attaching an event for errors js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, try-catch, throw

I'm looking for a hook to use whenever an error is fired. I'm aware that you can try/catch but I want something like jQuery's .error but bound to all errors.

Anyone know of anything like this?

Comment: what kind of error's , can you list some of them ?

Comment: var obj;

obj.something += "rawr";
//obj.something is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.onerror)

> Summary
>
> An event handler for runtime script errors.
>
> Note that some/many error events do not trigger window.onerror, you
>   have to listen for them specifically.